# C VS console opens for a very brief time while openng in exe

Tags: c, visual-studio, console, exe

When I open a program in C from the VS editor (I mean pressing the green button "Local windows debugger") the console opens, stays open and the program finishes noramlly.
However, when I try to run the program manually from the .ext file created, the program runs but the console opens for a brief time and closes immediately. How can I fix it?

Comment: When you execute an `exe` file the program runs all it's routines and exits, if you want the console to remain open you have to introduce a routine that makes it stop before the end, try asking for a character input at the end of `main` before the `return` statement e.g. `getchar();`. As for the debuger console, it does not close automatically, it waits for the user confirmation.

Comment: It's been some time since you accepted an answer, maybe it's time for you to review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)